# Bash - Extract kpartx output to variables

Tags: bash, automation

I want to extract the output off the kpartx tool:

```
add map loop18p1 (253:0): 0 1048576 linear 7:18 2048
add map loop18p2 (253:1): 0 1046528 linear 7:18 1050624
```

and then save loop18p1 and loop18p2 to $a and $b.

```
kpartx="$(sudo kpartx -av $IMAGE_FILE)"
read PART_FAT32 PART_NTFS <<<$(grep -o 'loop.p.' <<<"$kpartx")
a=/dev/mapper/$PART_FAT32
b=/dev/mapper/$PART_NTFS

echo $a
echo $b
```

but somehow it doesn't seem to work, I always get empty variables:

```
/dev/mapper/
/dev/mapper/
```

Kind regards,

jamefane

Comment: `kpartx="$(sduo kpartx -av $IMAGE_FILE)"` there is typo I guess, it should be `sudo`

Comment: Oh, thanks, i fixed that but my problem is still there :(

Comment: How do you expect that code to work? For one thing, `loop.p.` expects there to only be *one* character between the `p` in `loop` and the `p` separating the device and partition numbers, but in your examples, you have *two* characters.

Comment: ...beyond that, though, `read a b` reads only *one* line, putting the first word into `a` and all subsequent words into `b`. If you want to read *two* lines, it should be `{ read firstLine; read secondLine; } < <(...whatever...)` (note the use of a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), which lets you stream output from `grep` into your `read`s, vs your current code where you require the `grep` to completely finish, then write its output to a temporary file, then have `read` read from that tempfile).

Comment: BTW, note that all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell or operating system; lowercase names are reserved for application usage, and are thus what you should use for variable names you assign in your scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to keep working on this, but Charles Duffy swooped in and pretty much said the same thing via the comments, so I'll just leave this here for posterity.  My goal was to walk through the process of diagnosing the problem.

Let's walk through your code.  I'll use [this image](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2018-11-15/2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite.zip) for my tests.

You start with this:

```
kpartx="$(sudo kpartx -av $IMAGE_FILE)"
```

On my system, that means:

```
$ IMAGE_FILE=2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite.img
$ kpartx="$(sudo kpartx -av $IMAGE_FILE)"
$ echo "$kpartx"
loop3p1 : 0 89854 /dev/loop3 8192
loop3p2 : 0 3547136 /dev/loop3 98304
```

Your output may look different, but that should be sufficient for us to test out the remainder of the code.

Next you attempt to extract the device names from the `$kpartx` variable using a nested `<<<` expression:

```
$ read PART_FAT32 PART_NTFS <<<$(grep -o 'loop.p.' <<<"$kpartx")
```

This gets me:

```
$ echo $PART_FAT32
loop3p1
$ echo $PART_NTFS
```

In other words, `$PART_NTFS` is empty.  That's because `read` only operates on a single line, and your `grep` command outputs multiple lines.  The result of `grep -o 'loop.p.' <<<"$kpartx"` is:

```
$ grep -o 'loop.p.' <<<"$kpartx"
loop3p1
loop3p2
```

So you need to refactor how you're extracting those values.

Answer (score 0):

`loop.p.` doesn't match *either* `loop18p1` or `loop18p2`. At minimum, you'd need to fix the `grep` to be something like `grep -E -o 'loop[[:digit:]]+p[[:digit:]]+'` (`+` being a "one-or-more" modifier; so `[[:digit:]]+` matches one-or-more digits in POSIX ERE, which is the syntax that `grep -E` enables).

Better than that, though, is to be aware of the syntax of the content you're reading, rather than just trying to blind-match content.

```
{
  read -r _ _ part_fat32 _  # first line:  read third word into part_fat32
  read -r _ _ part_ntfs _   # second line: read third word into part_ntfs
} < <(sudo kpartx -av "$IMAGE_FILE")
a="/dev/mapper/$part_fat32"
b="/dev/mapper/$part_ntfs"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer a more generic way you may use dynamic variables for device letters. Notes: stderr is also redirected to grep in case kpartx can not map. declaration of array depends on shell.

```
# dynamic variable list for device letters
declare -a DEV=({a..z})

# assign kpartx results to device letters
for PART in $(sudo kpartx -av "$IMAGE_FILE" 2>&1 | grep -owE '(loop[0-9]+p[0-9]+)')
  do
    eval ${DEV[${i:-0}]}=/dev/mapper/$PART
    i=$((${i:-0}+1))
done

echo $a
echo $b
```